# How to align multiple images in canvas according to the given images in canvas?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas

I need the same effect in my website which is given in the example website.

Here is the example website: http://jsfiddle.net/x7uMh/103/

And Here is my current website: http://202.164.42.226/staging/designingtool/HTML1/single-product.html

In the website go to the `Choose model to customize` section and click on the product after that canvas will open and I want to use the same functionality in my website.

My website using jQuery.sparx file and fabric jQuery .

If you have any solution then please let us know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is best to include examples in your post. It is also good to describe what you have tried and what exactly is not working. Please update your post or expand in the comments.

Comment: i want to show the guide in canvas